# Drops being cleared, but still dropping

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So I am making a plugin, and everything works so far.

The only problem I have is that the chestplate lore wipes, and items sometimes drop twice, one with broken durability and the same stats. Any help is appreciated

```
package me.impatheimpaler.mmo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.entity.Skeleton;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Mobdrops extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

public List<String> t1h = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> t1c = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> t1l = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> t1b = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> t1s = new ArrayList<String>();

public static me.impatheimpaler.mmo.Main plugin;

public Mobdrops(Main main) {
    plugin = main;
}

@EventHandler
public void onDeath(EntityDeathEvent e) {

    Skeleton s = (Skeleton) e.getEntity();

    if (!(e.getEntity() instanceof Player)) {
        e.getDrops().clear();
          e.setDroppedExp(0);
      }

      if ((e.getEntity() instanceof Skeleton))  {
        Skeleton sk = (Skeleton)e.getEntity();
        if (sk.getCustomName() == null) {
          return;
        }
      }

    Random random = new Random();
    int rarity = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
    int chestdrop = random.nextInt(20) + 1;
    int legsdrop = random.nextInt(17) + 1;
    int helmdrop = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
    int bootsdrop = random.nextInt(11) + 1;
    int swordDrop = random.nextInt(15) + 1;


    if (helmdrop == 3) {
    ItemStack t1helm = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_HELMET);
    ItemMeta t1helmMeta = t1helm.getItemMeta();
    t1helmMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.WHITE + "Renegade's Torn Helmet");
    if (rarity == 3) {
    int hp = random.nextInt(20) + 33;
    t1h.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + hp);
    t1h.add(ChatColor.GOLD + "Legendary");
    }
    if (rarity == 2) {
    int hp = random.nextInt(10) + 20;
    t1h.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + hp);
    t1h.add(ChatColor.AQUA + "Normal");
    }
    if (rarity == 1) {
    int hp = random.nextInt(15) + 6;
    t1h.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + hp);
    t1h.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Poor");
    }
    t1helmMeta.setLore(t1h);
    t1helm.setItemMeta(t1helmMeta);
    s.getEquipment().setHelmet(t1helm);
    e.getDrops().add(t1helm);
    t1h.clear();
    }

    if (chestdrop == 7) {
    ItemStack t1chest = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_CHESTPLATE);
    ItemMeta t1chestMeta = t1chest.getItemMeta();
    t1chestMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.WHITE + "Renegade's Torn Chestplate");
    if (rarity == 3) {
    int hp = random.nextInt(20) + 72;
    t1c.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + hp);
    t1c.add(ChatColor.GOLD + "Legendary");
    }
    if (rarity == 2) {
    int hp = random.nextInt(30) + 33;
    t1c.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + hp);
    t1c.add(ChatColor.AQUA + "Normal");
    }
    if (rarity == 1) {
    int hp = random.nextInt(10) + 20;
    t1c.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + hp);
    t1c.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Poor");
    }
    t1chestMeta.setLore(t1c);
    t1chest.setItemMeta(t1chestMeta);
    s.getEquipment().setChestplate(t1chest);
    e.getDrops().add(t1chest);
    t1c.clear();
}

    if (legsdrop == 2) {
    ItemStack t1legs = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_LEGGINGS);
    ItemMeta t1legsMeta = t1legs.getItemMeta();
    t1legsMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.WHITE + "Renegade's Torn Leggings");
    if (rarity == 3) {
    int hp = random.nextInt(20) + 61;
    t1l.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + hp);
    t1l.add(ChatColor.YELLOW + "Legendary");
    }
    if (rarity == 2) {
    int hp = random.nextInt(20) + 33;
    t1l.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + hp);
    t1l.add(ChatColor.AQUA + "Normal");
    }
    if (rarity == 1) {
    int hp = random.nextInt(10) + 10;
    t1l.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + hp);
    t1l.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Poor");
    }
    t1legsMeta.setLore(t1l);
    t1legs.setItemMeta(t1legsMeta);
    s.getEquipment().setLeggings(t1legs);
    e.getDrops().add(t1legs);
    t1l.clear();
    }

    if (bootsdrop == 1) {
    ItemStack t1boots = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_BOOTS);
    ItemMeta t1bootsMeta = t1boots.getItemMeta();
    t1bootsMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.WHITE + "Renegade's Torn Boots");
    if (rarity == 3) {
    int hp = random.nextInt(20) + 23;
    t1b.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + hp);
    t1b.add(ChatColor.YELLOW + "Legendary");
    }
    if (rarity == 2) {
    int hp = random.nextInt(10) + 10;
    t1b.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + hp);
    t1b.add(ChatColor.AQUA + "Normal");
    }
    if (rarity == 1) {
    int hp = random.nextInt(5) + 6;
    t1b.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + hp);
    t1b.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Poor");
    }
    t1bootsMeta.setLore(t1b);
    t1boots.setItemMeta(t1bootsMeta);
    s.getEquipment().setBoots(t1boots);
    e.getDrops().add(t1boots);
    t1b.clear();
    }

    if (swordDrop == 3) {
    ItemStack t1sword = new ItemStack(Material.WOOD_SWORD);
    ItemMeta t1swordMeta = t1sword.getItemMeta();
    if (rarity == 3) {
        int min = random.nextInt(20) + 11;
        int max = random.nextInt(20) + 21;
        t1s.add(ChatColor.RED + "DMG: " + min + " - " + max);
        t1s.add(ChatColor.YELLOW + "Legendary");
    }
    if (rarity == 2) {
        int max = random.nextInt(10) + 21;
        int min = random.nextInt(10) + 11;
        t1s.add(ChatColor.RED + "DMG: " + min + " - " + max);
        t1s.add(ChatColor.AQUA + "Normal");
    }
    if (rarity == 1) {
        int min = random.nextInt(5) + 6;
        int max = random.nextInt(10) + 11;
        t1s.add(ChatColor.RED + "DMG: " + min + " - " + max);
        t1s.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Poor");
    }
    t1swordMeta.setLore(t1s);
    t1sword.setItemMeta(t1swordMeta);
    s.getEquipment().setItemInHand(t1sword);
    e.getDrops().add(t1sword);
    t1s.clear();
      }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Without knowing what the intent of the code is, it's impossible to give helpful advice on what's required to "fix" it. Format and comment through your code. Run a __debugger__. If you don't know what that is, read a __book__.

Comment: There's quite a few problems (assuming you want special items to drop from skeletons?) Your code reads "on any entity death, drop item" (including players) it's only canceled when it's a skeleton without a custom name. You should make use of a few "else if" between the `if (rarity == #)`'s because there's no point in wasting resources to check again. also you have stuff like 't1helmMeta.setLore(th1)' where 'th1' is **only** even set if one of the if statements are true, you should 'return' here

I can't really see a problem with so many others, I'm sorry.. maybe clear up your intentions?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues here, but I think the reason you are seeing duplicate items is because you are adding it to both the drop list as well as an equipment slot. When a mob has an item equipped it has a small chance of dropping that item. So essentially you are adding the item twice and occasionally one extra is dropping. Also, code formatting and readability is huge if you ever want to expand on this.

I don't normally do this, but I wanted to help you out. I'm doing this in notepad so please bare with any small errors. If there are any small mistakes let me know so I can update the code accordingly.

```
package me.impatheimpaler.mmo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.entity.Skeleton;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Mobdrops extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    public static me.impatheimpaler.mmo.Main plugin;

    public Mobdrops(Main main) {
        plugin = main;
    }

    private ItemStack AddArmorToDropList(EntityDeathEvent e, Material oMaterial, String strItemName, int intRarity, int T3Random, int T3Bonus, int T2Random, int T2Bonus, int T1Random, int T1Bonus) {
        ItemStack oItemStack = new ItemStack(oMaterial);
        ItemMeta oItemMeta = oItemStack.getItemMeta();
        oItemMeta.setDisplayName(strItemName);
        List<String> arrItemLore = new ArrayList<String>(); //Always use descriptive variable names

        Random random = new Random();
        if (intRarity == 3) {
            arrItemLore.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + (random.nextInt(T3Random) + T3Bonus));
            arrItemLore.add(ChatColor.GOLD + "Legendary");
        }
        else if (intRarity == 2) {
            arrItemLore.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + ()random.nextInt(T2Random) + T2Bonus);
            arrItemLore.add(ChatColor.AQUA + "Normal");
        }
        else { //Always use a final else to catch all exceptions
            arrItemLore.add(ChatColor.RED + "HP: +" + (random.nextInt(T1Random) + T1Bonus));
            arrItemLore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Poor");
        }
        oItemMeta.setLore(arrItemLore);
        oItemStack.setItemMeta(oItemMeta);
        e.getDrops().add(oItemStack);
    }
    private void AddWeaponToDropList(EntityDeathEvent e, Material oMaterial, String strItemName, int intRarity, int T3MinDmg, int T3MaxDmg, int T2MinDmg, int T2MaxDmg, int T1MinDmg, int T1MaxDmg) {
        ItemStack oItemStack = new ItemStack(oMaterial);
        ItemMeta oItemMeta = oItemStack.getItemMeta();
        oItemMeta.setDisplayName(strItemName);
        List<String> arrItemLore = new ArrayList<String>(); //Always use descriptive variable names

        Random random = new Random();
        if (intRarity == 3) {
            arrItemLore.add(ChatColor.RED + "DMG: " + T3MinDmg + " - " + T3MaxDmg);
            arrItemLore.add(ChatColor.GOLD + "Legendary");
        }
        else if (intRarity == 2) {
            arrItemLore.add(ChatColor.RED + "DMG: " + T2MinDmg + " - " + T2MaxDmg);
            arrItemLore.add(ChatColor.AQUA + "Normal");
        }
        else { //Always use a final else to catch all exceptions
            arrItemLore.add(ChatColor.RED + "DMG: " + T1MinDmg + " - " + T1MaxDmg);
            arrItemLore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Poor");
        }
        oItemMeta.setLore(arrItemLore);
        oItemStack.setItemMeta(oItemMeta);
        e.getDrops().add(oItemStack);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onDeath(EntityDeathEvent e) {

        Skeleton oSkeleton = null; //Never do a direct cast without being sure that the entity is what you think it is

        if (!(e.getEntity() instanceof Player)) { //Clear items and exp dropped
            e.getDrops().clear();
            e.setDroppedExp(0);
        }
        if (e.getEntity() instanceof Skeleton)  {
            if (oSkeleton.getCustomName() != null) {
                oSkeleton = (Skeleton) e.getEntity(); //Set oSkeleton value
            }
        }

        if (oSkeleton != null) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int intRarity = random.nextInt(3) + 1;

            if ((random.nextInt(6) + 1) == 3) { 
                AddArmorToDropList(e, Material.LEATHER_HELMET, ChatColor.WHITE + "Renegade's Torn Helmet", intRarity, 20, 33, 10, 20, 15, 6);
            }

            if ((random.nextInt(20) + 1) == 7) {
                AddArmorToDropList(e, Material.LEATHER_CHESTPLATE, ChatColor.WHITE + "Renegade's Torn Chestplate", intRarity, 20, 72, 30, 33, 10, 20);
            }

            if ((random.nextInt(17) + 1) == 2) {
                AddArmorToDropList(e, Material.LEATHER_LEGGINGS, ChatColor.WHITE + "Renegade's Torn Leggings", intRarity, 20, 61, 20, 33, 10, 10);
            }

            if ((random.nextInt(11) + 1) == 1) {
                AddArmorToDropList(e, Material.LEATHER_BOOTS, ChatColor.WHITE + "Renegade's Torn Boots", intRarity, 20, 23, 10, 10, 5, 6);
            }

            if ((random.nextInt(15) + 1) == 3) {
                int intT3Min = random.nextInt(20) + 11;
                int intT3Max = random.nextInt(20) + 21;
                int intT2Min = random.nextInt(10) + 11;
                int intT2Max = random.nextInt(10) + 21;
                int intT1Min = random.nextInt(5) + 6;
                int intT1Max = random.nextInt(10) + 11;

                AddWeaponToDropList(e, Material.WOOD_SWORD, ChatColor.WHITE + "RGAMinecraft's Sword", intRarity, intT3Min, intT2Max, intT2Min, intT3Max, intT1Min, intT1Max);
            }
        }
    }
}
```